# how can I cast int to 2D array's element?

Tags: python

I cannot know how to  cast int to 2D array's element.
My array is like

```
[['1', '2'], ['4', '3', '6'], ['10', '6'], [], ['300']]
```

so I wanna get an array like

```
[[1, 2], [4, 3, 6], [10, 6], [], [300]]
```

I tried

```
for i in range(len(array)):
  x =int(array[i])
```

and

```
y = str(''.join(array))
z = int(y)
```

and

```
list(map(int,array))
```

but all way happen error.
How can I do this?
I do not wanna use numpy in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply using `map` is not enough because you have a **nested** list. 
You can use `map` one the elements of the original list:

```
l=[['1', '2'], ['4', '3', '6'], ['10', '6'], [], ['300']]
il = [map(int,sl) for sl in l]
```

Resulting with

```
[[1, 2], [4, 3, 6], [10, 6], [], [300]]
```

BTW, your input is NOT 2D (as the number of elements in each sub-list is different), but rather a nested list.